# How do I escape apostraphes within an awk statement?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, escaping, apostrophe

I'm using bash shell on Mac Sierra.  How do I escape apostrophes within an awk statement?  I'm trying the below

```
localhost:myproject davea$ awk -F\, {printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id='\''%s'\'' where thirdparty_user_id='\''%s'\'';\n", $(NF-2),$(NF-1)} /tmp/myfile.csv
-bash: NF-2: command not found
-bash: NF-1: command not found
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>>  <<<
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
    missing }
```

but as you an see its resulting in a whole range of errors.  My goal is to extract the second and third columns from the CSV file and make an SQL statement out of them.

Comment: You have a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\047` for a single quote:

```
awk -F, '{
printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id=\047%s\047 where thirdparty_user_id=\047%s\047;\n",
$(NF-2),$(NF-1)}' /tmp/myfile.csv
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to solve all the syntax errors but how do I extract the second and third columns?  The above seems to be extracting the first and second columns.

Comment: I just took your example awk command which was working on 2 csv fields only. You can access any of these csv fields using `$1, $2, $3` etc.

Comment: For example you can use: `awk -F, '{printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id=\047%s\047 where thirdparty_user_id=\047%s\047;\n", $2, $3}' file.csv`